# How to remove rows in data frames with dates close to each other in R?

Tags: r, date, filter

I have longitudinal data in a data frame in long format in R, such that a person can be present on several rows, where each row has a specific date - but never the same date. Data is sorted by personal ID firstly and secondly by date, such that early dates for an individual comes first.

Following is what I would like to accomplish:
The first date for each individual should be kept. For the rest of the dates I want to remove all dates occurring within 30 days of a previous date for that person. But, if a row is removed, no other following dates should be compared to that date. The dates should be removed in order, from top to bottom. I.e. if a person has dates 14 May 2020, 20 May 2020, 22 May 2020 and 17 June 2020 I would like to remove the rows in the data frame with the two middle dates, as they are close to the first date: 14 May 2020. I have been able to do this with for loops, but it is not at all time efficient for big data. Does anybody know how I could solve this in a better way?

Comment: Please share some sample data in a reproducible format and we can help with this. `dput()` is a great command for making copy/pasteable data, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows. Please choose a smallish subset of data that illustrates the problem.

Comment: I will say that things like this where what happens on one iteration can influence what happens on subsequent iterations are not generally vectorizable---meaning `for` loops may be the best solution. But if you post what you've got, we can possibly improve the efficiency of your code. You could also look at parallel processing, e.g. using the `foreach` package.